# Adding Spring Kafka Maven dependency version 2.2.1.RELEASE encountered ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-kafka

I wanna use Kafka client in Spring boot.

After reading the [offical documentaion](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#quick-tour),

I added the maven dependency.

Then I tried to start Spring Boot. It throws

> ClassNotFoundException.
>   This class is '**org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecordInterceptor** '

**Could anyone can solve this problem?**

```
   Version:
          <spring.boot.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
          <spring.version>5.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    pom.xml:
       <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
       </dependency>
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
     </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Spring Boot, you should let boot manage the version, for Boot 2.2.1, the proper version is 2.3.3.

[Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#quick-tour).

But, when using Boot, you can omit the version and Boot will automatically use the right version.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```